# Using flask-login on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am using wtforms's model_form for the login formlike this:

```
LoginForm = model_form(User, Form, field_args= {
                                                'user_email' : { 'validators' : [Required(), Email()]},
                                                'user_password' : { 'validators' : [Required()]}
                                                 })
```

my user model is like this:

```
class User(UserMixin, ndb.Model):
    user_email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
    user_password = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

But I need to add the verify function from the flask-login [documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [this](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/use-flask-login-to-add-user-authentication-to-your-python-application) tutorial - how can I implement this verify function for authentication as part of the form?

```
User.query.filter_by(user_email=user_email,user_password=user_password).first()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get as instance of your model like below:

```
@login_manager.user_loader 
def load_user(email):
     return User.query().filter(User.email==email,User.password=password).get()
```